# select range using c# excel interop

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop, excel-interop

I am unable to select range using excel interop in C#. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here. I am very new to excel interop

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\s1.xlsx");

        Excel.Range xlTestRange;
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[2];

        xlTestRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        xlTestRange.Select();
        xlWorkbook.Save();
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        xlApp.UserControl = true;
        xlApp.Quit();


    }
```

Comment: how do you know the selection isn't working if you are closing the workbook and quitting the application?

Comment: I missed out the save line while pasting here

Comment: when the code is running it givens the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Select method of Range class failed

Comment: You don't need to set `UserControl` if you are going to call `Quit`. I ran this code in LINQPad and it worked fine on my test spreadsheet. Note that `Sheets[]` is indexed starting at one.

Comment: Just a FYI, I copied your code and ran it just fine. Anything special in the 2nd sheet by chance?

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me in LINQPad:

```
var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
var xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"path-to-excel-file");
var xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

var xlTestRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
xlTestRange.Select();
xlWorkbook.Save();

xlWorkbook.Close();
xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Your code above didn't work on C# :(

However when I ran the code below it worked fine

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\s1.xlsx");

            Excel.Range xlTestRange;
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[2];
            xlWorksheet.Select();

            xlTestRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            xlTestRange.Select();
            xlWorkbook.Save();
            xlWorkbook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();

Comment: I think this was the missing line -> xlWorksheet.Select();

Comment: Ah - it worked for me because I was using the one and only worksheet.